how to maintain Selected Rows from a DataGridView Control after inserting,updating & deleting with bindingsource in vb.net
I'm Trying to maintain Selected Rows from a DataGridView Control after inserting,updating & deleting with bindingsource in vb.net.
I've also used the "DataBindingComplete" event datagridview but it doesn't work as there might be something wrong with my code.
For example, if I insert a record from the button event after loading the data, the selected row is automatically in the new record position and if I update a record from the button event after loading the data, the selected row is automatically in the update record position and if I delete the record in the button event, the selected row is in the previous record of the record that has been deleted .
Please Guide me
Thanks
 Dim CatProdService As New CatProdService()
    Private bindingSource As BindingSource = Nothing
    Private selectedOrder As String
    Private selectedIndex As Integer
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadData1()
    End Sub
    Private Sub LoadData1()
        Dim CatProd = CatProdService.Getitem()
        bindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of CatProd)(CType(CatProdService.Getitem(), IList(Of CatProd)))}
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource
        DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
    End Sub
    Private Function GetSELECT() As CatProd
        Return If(DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count = 0, Nothing, TryCast(DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).OwningRow.DataBoundItem, CatProd))
    End Function    

Private Sub DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DataBindingComplete
        If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedOrder) _
            AndAlso (e.ListChangedType = ListChangedType.Reset)) Then
            If (bindingSource.List.Count > 0) Then
                selectedIndex = bindingSource.Find("CatProd", selectedOrder)
                If (selectedIndex <= 0) Then
                    selectedIndex = 0
                End If

                DataGridView1.Rows(selectedIndex).Selected = True
            Else
                selectedOrder = String.Empty
            End If

        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub BtnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnDelete.Click
        Try
            Dim SelectDgv = GetSELECT()
            If MessageBox.Show("Delete selected record?", "CONFIRM!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel) = DialogResult.Yes Then
                CatProdService.DeleteItem(SelectDgv.ID)
                LoadData1()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "TEST", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End Try
    End Sub
  Private Sub Btnsave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnsave.Click
        Dim CatProd = CatProdService.GetByCatProd(txtCatProd.Text)
        Dim DesCatProd = CatProdService.GetByDesCatProd(txtDesCatProd.Text)
        Dim isValidID As Boolean
        Boolean.TryParse(btxtid.Text, isValidID)

        Dim userid2 = CatProdService.GetCatProdById2(CBool(isValidID))
        Try
            If txtCatProd.TextLength > 3 Then
                MessageBox.Show("CatProd Product Only 3 Characters or Digits")
                Return
            End If
            If userid2 Is Nothing Then
                If CatProd IsNot Nothing Then
                    MessageBox.Show("CatProd Product already exists")
                    Return
                End If
                If DesCatProd IsNot Nothing Then
                    MessageBox.Show("DesCatProd Product already exists")
                    Return
                End If

                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCatProd.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDesCatProd.Text) Then
                    MsgBox("Required fill CatProd,DesCatProd", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Information")
                    Return
                End If
                'insert new record
                CatProdService.InsertCatProd(New CatProd() With {
            .CatProd = txtCatProd.Text,
            .DesCatProd = txtDesCatProd.Text
        })
            Else
                'Update record
                CatProdService.UpdateCatProd(New CatProd() With {
             .CatProd = txtCatProd.Text,
            .DesCatProd = txtDesCatProd.Text,
            .ID = CInt(btxtid.Text)
             })

            End If
            MessageBox.Show("Successfull")

            'btnOk.Enabled = False
            'btnOk.BackColor = Color.DarkGray
            LoadData1()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "TEST", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

        End Try
    End Sub



You should use a list and add that as a datasource to a bindingsource component. Then add the bindingsource component as a datasource to the grid. This only needs to be done once.
Afterwhich, just manage everything i.e. add/update/delete, from the list and refresh the bindings when complete. The grid will up date and automatically retain position.
E.g.
Public Class Form1


Private fakeTeams As New List(Of Team)


Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    fakeTeams = CreateFakeTeams()
    gridTeams.DataSource = TeamBindingSource
    TeamBindingSource.DataSource = fakeTeams
End Sub

Private Sub bnAddNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnAddNew.Click
    fakeTeams.Add(New Team With {.Name = "New Team", .City = "New City", .League = "New League", .Division = "New Division"})
    TeamBindingSource.ResetBindings(False)
End Sub

Private Function CreateFakeTeams() As List(Of Team)
    Dim teams As New List(Of Team) From {
        New Team With {.Name = "Yankees", .City = "New York", .League = "American", .Division = "East"},
        New Team With {.Name = "Red Sox", .City = "Boston", .League = "American", .Division = "East"},
        New Team With {.Name = "Blue Jays", .City = "Toronto", .League = "American", .Division = "East"},
        New Team With {.Name = "Orioles", .City = "Baltimore", .League = "American", .Division = "East"},
        New Team With {.Name = "Rays", .City = "Tampa Bay", .League = "American", .Division = "East"}
    }
    Return teams
End Function

Private Sub bnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnRemove.Click
    Dim selectedRow = gridTeams.CurrentRow.Index
    fakeTeams.RemoveAt(selectedRow)
    TeamBindingSource.ResetBindings(False)
End Sub

End Class

Public Class Team

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property City As String
    Public Property League As String
    Public Property Division As String

End Class


Thank you for your response. Private TeamBindingSource As BindingSource = Nothing You have to create a private variable  and TeamBindingSource.DataSource = fakeTeams change to TeamBindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = fakeTeams} . and for bnAddNew event No mantain selection

No additional events are required as the bindingsource is already designed to fire events to update the UI. Just by adding/removing/editing in code, the updates are implemented in the UI.
